# How can I merge another array into another project property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have 2 arrays

## console.log(this.items) = userGroups

```
[
    {
        "id": 63,
        "name": "URLGROUP-1643836551908"
    }
]
```

## console.log(urls)

userGroup can have URLs

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 110,
            "group_id": 63,
            "url": "https://www.apple.com",
            "url_num": 1,
            "max_iteration": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 111,
            "group_id": 63,
            "url": "https://www.google.com",
            "url_num": 2,
            "max_iteration": 2
        }

    ]
]
```

I'm trying to combine them like this : id, name, url

```
[
    {
        "id": 63,
        "name": "URLGROUP-1643836551908",
        "url": [
        {
            "id": 110,
            "group_id": 63,
            "url": "https://www.apple.com",
            "url_num": 1,
            "max_iteration": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 111,
            "group_id": 63,
            "url": "https://www.google.com",
            "url_num": 2,
            "max_iteration": 2
        }

    ]
    }
]
```

I've tried merge, and I don't get a good result at all.
I'm about to do for-loop within a forloop, but that will be bad for performance.

What should I do in case ?

If I do this

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < urls.length; j++) {
        if (i == j) {
            this.items[i].urls = urls[j]
        }
    }
}
```

console.log(this.items)

I kind of get what I want:

```
[
    {
        "id": 63,
        "name": "URLGROUP-1643836551908",
        "details": [
            {
                "id": 110,
                "group_id": 63,
                "url": "https://www.acme.com",
                "url_num": 1,
                "max_iteration": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Are we guaranteed that there will only be 1 item in each array? (Also - merge performs nested for-loops! Nested loops don't *necessarily* have poor performance; sometimes they are unavoidable!)

Comment: Why does the second array have *nested* arrays? Why is that useful? Secondly, are the `group_id` unique? Can you give an example in your question that is just a tiny bit larger, so we can see where the variation occurs and what would be the expected result for it?

Comment: @GershomMaes : I only show 1 element in the array as a sample it can have more element.

Comment: @trincot I updated my post with more information. this.userGroups is an array of userGroup and each userGroup can have one or many urls.

Comment: I still don't get why the second object has a `[ [ ] ]` structure. Is there any possibility that the outer array has more than one element? If so, what will be the meaning of that separation? If not, then why is that level there at all? It would be good if the example clarifies this by having multiple entries in the outer array...

Comment: Your attempt could be simplified by removing the loop over `j`, since you just want `i === j`, so no `j` is needed... just use `i` instead of `j`. But this assumes that the order of elements in the first array is the same as in the second, and have the corresponding group relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the example is not varied enough to be sure, I will assume that the second array (of arrays) has grouped items with the same `group_id` value in the same subarray.

You could create a `Map` keyed by `group_id` (the first found in a subarray), and assign to each the corresponding subarray.

Then map the first array to objects extended with a `url` property that is taken from the `Map`, based on the objects `id` property:

```js
let userGroups = [{"id": 63,"name": "URLGROUP-1643836551908"}];

let urls = [[{"id": 110,"group_id": 63,"url": "https://www.apple.com","url_num": 1,"max_iteration": 2},{"id": 111,"group_id": 63,"url": "https://www.google.com","url_num": 2,"max_iteration": 2}]];

let urlsMap = new Map(urls.map(arr => [arr[0].group_id, arr]));
let result = userGroups.map(obj => ({...obj, url: urlsMap.get(obj.id)}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your answer looks pretty advanced. Thank-you. If I used my forloops `for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < urls.length; j++) {
        if (i == j) {
            this.items[i].urls = urls[j]
        }
    }
}` how bad is it in term of performance ?

Comment: In terms of performance if will become worse when the array becomes large, but the main problem is that it is unnecessary to have the inner loop, since you already know you want `i` to equal `j`, so you are just doing `this.items[i].urls = urls[i]`. So the inner loop is wasting time. Secondly however, how can you be sure you need that `urls` entry?  You would need to check that it corresponds in term of `group_id`, which your code doesn't do.